# git repo says it's up-to-date after pull but files are not updated

Tags: git, repository, checkin

I have 3 repos. A bare repo which I use as a master repo, a dev repo in which I make and test changes, and prod repo from which scripts are executed in the prod environment.

After I have tested changes in the dev repo I push them to the bare repo and they are auto pulled down into the prod repo on a cronjob using a basic script (carrying out git pull command).

I followed through the above procedure for a change, but the altered file will not update in the prod repo.

- The change is checked in and pushed in the dev repo
- The pull has been done to the prod repo
- The git logs for all repos are identical and all show the checkin for this change
- git branch gives me "* master" for all repos
- git status for all repos gives me:
   # On branch master
   nothing to commit, working directory clean
- git pull gives me "Already up-to-date" for the dev & prod repos

Using git extensions for a graphical view, it appears each repo is up to date and at the head.

I've tried:

```
git checkout HEAD  
git pull origin master  
git reset --hard HEAD  
git reset --hard origin/master  
git reset origin/master
```

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Try this:

```
 git fetch --all
 git reset --hard origin/master
```

Explanation:

`git fetch` downloads the latest from remote without trying to merge or rebase anything.

Comment: Hey, yeah that worked, Thanks!. I still don't get how nothing flagged as being out sync and logs suggested that the repos all matched, but it solved the problem anyhow! I'll read up more on fetch...

Comment: Yea this happened to me as well, `git fetch` on it's own didn't pull my changes. But `git fetch --all` solved it. Weird.

Comment: thank you, it worked for me! Then the `git pull` finally downloads the latest version.

Comment: Awesome, worked for me. I deleted a local directory and `git pull` was saying I was up to date, but this refetched the deleted directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For me my forked branch was not in sync with the master branch. So I went to bitbucket and synced and merged my forked branch and then tried to take the pull. Then it worked fine.

Comment: I was using forked repository for the first time and didn't realize this scenario. Synced my forked repository with the upstream (original) repository and then could get changes to my local.  _Reference: https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork_

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in getting a specific local branch up to date:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/[name of your branch]
```

Answer (score 0):

Our upstream repo had wrong `master` tag so was forced to delete it in our fork repo:

```
git reset --hard upstream/master 
git tag -d master
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because I got to this page with the same problem: Make sure that you *really* `git push`ed your changes.

I'm using PyCharm and somehow just missed that.