# Github: Cant pull the repository inside the amazon ec2. Exhibits message that the github repo is already present

Tags: github

I had pushed a github repo 2 days back in my amazon ec2 inside the frontend folder. After pushing he repo a folder for it called(bank in this case) was created inside the frontend folder.

Because of some changes in the code i removed the banks folder from the frontend folder and once again pushed the new update github repo.But the folder isnt being shown.

bank folder is not visible.

How to rectify this.`When i pull the repo message is exihibited

```
        ubuntu@ip:~/frontend$ git pull github15 master
        **output:**
        From https://github.com/naikvaibhav/bank-app
        * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
        * [new branch]      master     -> github15/master
        Already up-to-date.

       but when i go through the frontend folder, i get this as the 
       ubuntu@ip:~/frontend$ ls
       **output:**
       news-app  pepper-cloud-blog  projects-profile  wallpaper- 
       gallery  weather-app `
```

Comment: Found solution to the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411366/git-repo-says-its-up-to-date-after-pull-but-files-are-not-updated

Answer (score 0):

the solution is first we need to check all the remotes using the cmd
             git fetch --all
then type the cmd
             git reset --hard origin/master